# Syntax Error Python: 'return outside function'

Tags: python, function, time

Trying to use a function in python to return time with hour and minutes... keep getting an error with the return statement

```
def return_time(hour, minutes):
    time = ""

if hour < 10:
    time += "0" + str(hour)
else:
    time += str(hour)
time += ":"
if minutes < 10:
    time += "0" + str(minutes)
else:
    time += str(minutes)
return time
```

Comment: Hi interesting, I believe you might be able to do it with `print(f"{hour:02d}:{minute:02d}")`

Comment: You can't return a variable that you assigned locally, and you are trying to return it globally, add an indentation

Comment: Yes; the line that says `return` on it needs to be inside the function. It isn't, so you get an error that says it is outside. Why is this confusing? Please re-read whatever tutorial material you are learning from, and make sure you understand how indentation works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Python doesn't use brackets/braces to keep track of blocks like some other languages (C++, Java, etc.), it is very particular about indentation. The way your code is written, the entirety of `return_time()` is

```py
def return_time(hour, minutes):
    time = ""
```

since the next line after that is non indented. This is an easy fix.

```py
def return_time(hour, minutes):
    time = ""

    if hour < 10:                # stay indented!
        time += "0" + str(hour)
    else:
        time += str(hour)
    time += ":"
    if minutes < 10:
        time += "0" + str(minutes)
    else:
        time += str(minutes)
    return time
```

Also, as @IronMan commented, this particular function is pretty easy to implement in a single line with an f-string.

```py
def return_time(hour, minutes):
    return f"{hour:02d}:{minutes:02d}"
```

An f-string (indicated by the `f` before the quotes) evaluates the variables within the braces and before the `:` and converts it to a string. The text after the `:` describes the format, which in this case is "exactly two digits, preceded by a 0 if there are less than two digits".

You might also be interested in `time.strftime()`.